# Problems updating the View on Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

i am trying to make a Form of SELECT boxes in MeteorJS. Everytime I change one SELECT box, I want the other SELECT boxes show different values, maybe this picture can help... 
[image: Change "Gebäude" and "Etage" changes its values]

How I solved it:

```
"use-strict";
if (Meteor.isClient) {
Session.set('cho',false);
Session.set('cho2',false);
Session.set('cho3',false);

      var building=["C1","C2","W1"],
          floor= ["4","5","6","38","50"];

        Template.body.events({
            "change #sel_geb" : function(eve,eva){
                var a = $(eve.target).val();
                if(a==="C1"){
                    Session.set('cho', true);
                    Session.set('cho2',false);
                    Session.set('cho3', false);
                    Meteor.flush();
                }else if (a ==="C2"){
                    floor.splice(0,1);
                    Session.set('cho2', true);
                    Session.set('cho3', false);
                    Session.set('cho', false);
                    Meteor.flush();
                }else{
                    Session.set('cho3', true);
                    Session.set('cho2', false);
                    Session.set('cho', false);
                }
            }
        });

        Template.etage.helpers({
            floor: function(){
                if(Session.equals('cho',true)){
                    return ["4"];
                }else if(Session.equals('cho2',true)){
                    return ["5","6"];
                }else if(Session.equals('cho3',true)){
                    return ["38","50"];
                }else{
                    return ["4"];
                }
            }
        });
```

Template-File:

```
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Mitarbeiter</label>
            <select class="form-control">
                {{> mitarbeiter}}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Gebäude</label>
            <select id="sel_geb" class="form-control" >
                {{> gebaeude}}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Etage</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="sel_eta">
                {{> etage}}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Raum</label>
            <select class="form-control">
                {{> raum}}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Aufgabe</label>
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>Aufbau/Prüfung</option>
                <option>Abbau</option>
                <option>Support</option>
                <option>Wöchentlicher Check</option>
                <option>täglicher Precheck</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Veranstalltungsname</label>
            <input type="text" id="presiname" class="form-control" placeholder="Veranstalltungsname">
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Weiter</button>
        <button type="cancel" class="btn btn-danger">Beenden</button>
    </div>
    </form>
<template name="mitarbeiter">
    {{#each names}}
        <option>{{this}}</option>
        {{/each}}
</template>
<template name="gebaeude">
    {{#each building}}
        <option>{{this}}</option>
        {{/each}}
</template>
<template name="etage">
    {{#each floor}}
        <option>{{this}}</option>
        {{/each}}
</template>
<template name="raum">
    {{#each room}}
        <option>{{this}}</option>
        {{/each}}
</template>
```

Everyting is working fine but I don't think this is the best way to solve this problem. Does someone have a better Idea? Would be very grateful.

Comment: What is your specific issue? Performance? Modularity? If it's simply code style then it's a matter of opinion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Güten tag Hicham,

It looks like you're trying to build a set of cascading menus. Your code looks functional but excessively complex. You are mixing data with code which means that adding buildings, floors, and rooms will require code changes.

Instead of maintaining separate arrays for the 3 levels, consider making an object that keeps the entire hierarchy, ex:

```
var gebaüde = [
  { name: "C1", etagen: [
    { anzahl: 4, räume: [ "Raum C1-4-1", "Raum C1-4-2" ]},
  ]},
  { name: "C2", etagen: [
    { anzahl: 5, räume: [ "Raum C2-5-1", "Raum C2-5-2" ]},
    { anzahl: 6, raüme: [ "Raum C2-6-1", "Raum C2-6-2" ]},
  ]},
  { name: "W1", etagen: [
    { anzahl: 38, räume: [ "Raum W1-38-1", "Raum W1-38-2" ]},
    { anzahl: 50, raüme: [ "Raum W1-50-1", "Raum W1-50-2" ]},
  ]}
];
```

Then your code can just access any level of this hierarchy and automatically get all the possible options below it.

Secondly, in a cascading menu design, when a user changes a menu selection, you only have to reset the menus *below* that level. You can simplify your code by automatically making the *next* menu selection if there only happens to be a single choices at that level but leaving the dependent choice blank if there are > 1 options. You shouldn't have to do anything at the levels above the one that was just changed.

Finally, you don't have to have a session variable for every level. You can keep an entire object in a session variable, in your case `{ gebaüde: value, etage: value, raum: value }`

Comment: I would add to this that you don't really need to use a `Session` variable here. Use a `ReactiveVar` or `ReactiveDict` unless you need to access the selection outside the current template.